# Selecting by data- attribute with jQuery - works in chrome, not firefox. Alternative?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

This is a sample element:

```
<textarea type="text" data-class-changer="question" class="questioninputcss" data-integer-question="877"></textarea>
```

This jQuery script works in Chrome, but not in firefox:

```
$("#reset").click(function(){
    $("[data-integer-question").attr("class", "questioninputcss");
});
```

I also tried it with an asterisk, like this: `$("*[data-integer-question")`, but that doesn't work either.

Chrome does not produce an error, and it works correctly.

Firefox does not work, and produces this error:

`Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [data-integer-question`

How can I work around this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a simple typo in your code.  The code should read:

```
$("#reset").click(function(){
    $("textarea[data-integer-question]").attr("class", "questioninputcss");
});
```

You omitted the trailing square bracket `]`.

Comment: I expected chrome to die if I typed it wrong.. LOL :( Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is a missing `']'` as shown :

```
$("#reset").click(function(){
    $("[data-integer-question]").attr("class", "questioninputcss");
});
```